# git orphan branch, files showing in multiple branches

Tags: git

I have 1 `git repository` with 2 `branches` the standard `master` branch and a `dev` branch created with `git checkout --orphan dev` i then removed everything in this branch by doing `git rm -rf .` I then ran my `commit` and `checkout master`

I added in a file into this branch that holds all my database information, and is intended to be an untracked file using git.  When I `checkout dev` the file is there too, so I modify the file and decide to try `checkout master` and what happened?  The file was changed there too...

So what I need to do, is figure out how to stop all files from migrating between branches with completely different history whether they are tracked or not.   I'm not sure how to fix this, or if it's even possible -- so any help in this is appreciated.

Comment: Probably you meant `git checkout --orphan dev`?

Comment: How did you try to untrack your "file that holds all [your] database information"? Are you sure you untracked it correctly?

Comment: As for your problem, I think you could add 2 remotes, although you would have to specify which branch you are pulling from.

Comment: I actually did do `git checkout --orphan dev` that was a typo on my part.

Comment: @trysis I am sure it's untracked completely, in the master branch it is not in the repo at all.  if I clone the repo on another machine, it does not contain the files it shouldn't.  But when I add the file to master, and then checkout dev it is in there as well when I haven't added it to this filetree

Comment: Do you try to clone the other branch before or after you add `my-untracked-file` to `master`? (Sorry, it's just easier if you give things names when you're asking questions.)

Comment: just tried something..  `mkdir test && cd test && git init && touch .gitignore && vi .gitignore` added `file.yml` to the gitignore which file doesn't exist yet.  `git checkout --orphan dev` then `touch file.yml`.. then i run `git checkout master` and `file.yml` shows up there when it wasn't created on that branch.. untracked files go to all branches when they shouldn't...  that's what i need to fix..

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout` keeps changes to local files that are not committed first.

```
To prepare for working on <branch>, switch to it by updating the index and the
files in the working tree, and by pointing HEAD at the branch. **Local
modifications to the files in the working tree are kept**, so that they can be
committed to the <branch>.
```

It seems this includes files that are not tracked first. The `-f` option ignores this, so all local changes are thrown away. This seems to be what you want.

Comment: Having two remotes isn't logical as both remotes would be the same github repo.  My master branch is the current version of the 'live' system that I periodically make changes to.. this is very hacky atm..  'dev' is my re-write of the same system.. 

on my local machine, i have files that are intentially untracked 'parameters.yml' for instance..  if on master I edit the db name to 'mydb' - I need not commit as the file is untracked as it should be..

Comment: but when i checkout dev at this point, the same file has been changed to what i did on the other branch despite the seperate history.. so files are being 'shared' between the two branches when they shouldn't be.

Comment: You can have 2 remotes in the same folder pointing to different branches of the same repo, I believe. Regardless, I don't like that option, I was just listing as many *possibilities* as I could think of.

Comment: it is a private repo actually...  and i did rm -rf all files in my dev branch before i did anything to it.. It's also the same project, one is just a re-write from the ground up.  check my comment just under my question and you'll see my latest test that still has the issue in it

Comment: I didn't understand your question before (still don't, completely), so I rewrote it to answer your actual question.

Comment: i have the same file in 2 branches, in the same location ( should be there with different data ).. changing the file contents to be correct in one branch, changes the file contents on the other branch despite the other branch having a completely different history...  untracked files are being shared across all branches which should not be the case if it has a seperate history..  that's the problem i'm having

Comment: Did you read my new answer? If you don't commit your changes first, they are kept after `git checkout`, whether you tracked them or not.

Comment: Sorry, you wrote that comment before I changed the answer and I can't tell time.

Comment: So was that the problem @Justin?

Comment: If all the changes are in unchanged files, there is nothing to commit.. let me run that test to see if it happens again.

Comment: still happens...  when i checkout dev and `touch file.yml` being an untracked file.. run `git commit -am "some change"` and checkout master, file is there.. rm file.yml then commit in master and checkout dev, file is gone...

Comment: should note the communication between me and github isn't a problem.. this is purely between branches on my local machine

Comment: You say when you commit your file then `checkout master`, your file is there, then remove the file, `checkout dev`, the file is gone... Isn't this what you want? Don't you want your file to be in `master` but not `dev`?

Comment: @Justin, I just changed my answer (again). We should both really learn to RTFM.

Comment: Nope still does it, thanks for spending the time trying to help figure this out.. I think it's a lost cause.. changing the contents of file.yml on branch dev, changes the contents of file.yml on branch master too...  no worries, thanks again for spending the time.

Comment: You're welcome, that's what we're here for. I hope you find *some* solution that works for you, best of luck.